# Ensure authenticated user can only update their own record

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, jackson

Suppose I have two entities as follows:

```java
@Entity
public class ClassA {
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
     }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany
    private Set<ClassB> classBs = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class ClassB {
    private Long id;
    private String name;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

That is, ClassA contains a Set of ClassB. And a resource like so to update ClassA:

```java
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ClassA update(@RequestBody ClassA a){
    // Update code here
}
```

and then in a DAO (using hibernate) the following is called to update ClassA in the database:

```java
@Override
public ClassA save(ClassA classA) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(classA);
    return classA;
}
```

In an **update** scenario if an authenticated user changes the `id` of an instance of `ClassB` to an `id` belonging to another user we find that there are no protections from stopping the user updating objects which do not belong to them. Are there any methods of preventing this? What is best practice to prevent this from happening (i.e. preventing them updating another users `classB` details)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Access Control using @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize):

> **Access Control using @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize**
>
> The most obviously useful annotation is `@PreAuthorize` which decides whether a method can actually be invoked or not. For example (from the"Contacts" sample application)
>
> ```java
> @PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
> public void create(Contact contact);
> ```
>
> which means that access will only be allowed for users with the role "ROLE_USER". Obviously the same thing could easily be achieved using a traditional configuration and a simple configuration attribute for the required role. But what about:
>
> ```java
> @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#contact, 'admin')")
> public void deletePermission(Contact contact, Sid recipient, Permission permission);
> ```
>
> Here we’re actually using a method argument as part of the expression to decide whether the current user has the "admin" permission for the given contact. The built-in `hasPermission()` expression is linked into the Spring Security ACL module through the application context, as we’llsee below. You can access any of the method arguments by name as expression variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is called *business logic*. Hibernate has no notion that the `id` field is meant to denote a user. It won't stop you from setting the field to any value you want.

The code that is calling this, that is changing the ID field, needs to be aware of the limitations of the `id` field, and prevent the user from changing it. You should have a business layer in between your UI and your DAO that does this sort of checking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate what you're saying. In this case we do have a service layer between the controller and DAO and so using logic in between would be ok to sort this out. I suppose that the question is more asking is it possible to automatically have hibernate (or possibly spring/spring-security) do this work for you? Or if methods to do this are known and documented somewhere.